# Calling a function in one of the components in the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Suppose I have this:

```
const navtest = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Stuff: {screen: Screen2},
    Stuff2: {screen: Screen3},
});
```

And I'm currently viewing Stuff2/Screen3. And I have some function in my HomeScreen component, say XYZ( ). On the basis of any certain action on my current route ( Screen3 ), how do I call that function XYZ( ) in HomeScreen?

My Routes file which directly links to index.js.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

const navtest= StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Stuff: {screen: Screen2},
    Stuff2: {screen: Screen3},
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('navtest', () => navtest);
```

and in my HomeScreen file

```
 export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {one: '0'};
        }

        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null,
        };

        functionToPass() {
            console.log('Function accessed');
            this.setState({one: 'X'});
        }

        render() {
            const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigate('Stuff', {ABC: 'abc'})}>
                        <Text>
                            {this.state.one}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you navigating from Home to Screen3? Then you can pass you function down as a param to be available in the navigation state. E.g. `this.props.navigation.navigate(‘Stuff2’, { someFunc: someFuncFromHome });` then, in your Screen3, you can invoke the function like this: `this.props.navigation.state.params.someFunc();`

If Home is not the previous route, then maybe the function should be extracted outside of the Home component and use a redux action or similar things to achieve the same result.

---

Follow up:
There are a few ways that I think that may be able to help you.

1) Introduce Redux to your app. This is a good use case for redux as this state can be manipulated from anywhere in the app. Dispatch the same redux action from any where in the app, and the HomeScreen can read from redux.

2) If you don't want redux in your app yet, maybe you can keep the state in a navigator wrapper component like the one in my comment earlier.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { one: '0' };
  }

  yourRootChangeFunc() {
    this.setState({ one: 'X' });
  }

  render() { 
    return <App screenProps={{ rootChange: this.rootChange, one: this.state.one }} /> 
  } 
}
```

Then you can access `one` in other screens with `this.props.screenProps.one`

3) Another way is use `setParams`, which you can setParams for a specific screen by passing in the key of the route.

In HomeScreen component:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  ...
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ one: '0' });
  }

  render() {
    const { state: { params = {} } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      ...
      <View>
        {params.one || '0'} // this is because currently there is no way to set a default params for a route
      </View>
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Then in Screen2 component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Screen2 extends Component {
  onPress = () => {
    const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
        params: { one: 'X' },
        key: this.props.navigation.state.params.homeKey,
   })
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction)
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>Screen2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This way, pressing on Screen2 text in Screen2 will change the params for HomeScreen. Then when go back to HomeScreen, we can see that the text changed from '0' to 'X'.

Comment: This can work like
`onPress = {() => navigate('Stuff', {callFunction: ()=> this.reqFunction()}`

but lets say you have a stack of 10 routes. Or even more. If you'l have to call all of those functions which will call their previous route's function and that would be super ugly.

I used to do something like this with the previous react-native-navigator, by putting the function as a navigator prop.
`<Navigator mainFunction = {this.someFunction} ... >`

and then to call it, `this.props.navigator.props.mainFunction()`

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the `dispatch()` function can do something like this?

Comment: Is you mainFunction the same function for all the pages in the navigator? Or are there different functions for each page to pass down to the next page? If the mainFunction should be an overall function to be used anywhere in the Navigator, then you can pass it down to the navigator with screenProps, similar to how it works before. E.g. const App = StackNavigator({...}); return <App screenProps={{ mainFunction: yourMainFunction }} />;

Comment: Can you better explain your use case here? I don’t think I’m understanding it correctly. From what I can tell, maybe the rootchanger function should not live on HomeScreen as it’s a function on the HomePage component that you want to be accessible anywhere. Maybe we can do something like defining the function as an instance method with the navigator as a component. E.g class App extends Component { yourRootChangeFunc() {} render() { return <App screenProps={{ rootChange: this.rootChange }} /> } } sorry if I’m not as helpful as I want to be.

Comment: Have a look at my code please. Updated above.
I want that functionToPass() in Homescreen to be (kinda like a global) accessible in all other screens.

Comment: Edited my response above with the followup. hope that helps!

Comment: @hyb175 Your first paragraph about passing the function as a param worked fine here for me, thank you so much.